# How to get select box option value in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I made a simple application on Pythonanywhere using Flask framework. When I submit a form, in the console logs I see that all information is transferred. But I don't need the name of selected item in select box, I need its value (id).

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="carCarcass" class="col-lg-6 control-label">Кузов</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="carCarcass" name="carCarcass">
            <option value="0" SELECTED>-</option>
            {% for carcass in CARCASSES %}
                <option value="{{ loop.index }}">{{ carcass }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to get via `request.form['carCarcass']` it returns the string that is between option tags.

How do I access the value?

Comment: where does `{{ loop.index }}` come from?

Comment: @corvid It's a standard part of the jinja2 `for` tag: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for

Comment: So to be clear, you're getting the value `{{ carcass }}` at `request.form['carCarcass']` instead of the value of `{{ loop.index }}`? It is the browser that passes along the value of the form, not Flask, and no browser I know of behaves the way you are describing. Am I misreading this?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know how, but after a batch of project restarts, the code started to work.


PS: Before I started to restart my project, I had _<option name=_ instead of _<option value=_. So, maybe changes applied not immediately.

Comment: Hello Chika. Would you please add the rest of your flask application code (either in this question or in pastebin) so that we can get a test instance up and running?

Comment: I think it is not necessary, because as I said it is now working.

Comment: For future reference, you do need to restart/reload the webapp, and you also need to refresh/reload the webpage that you were testing the form on.

Answer (score 0):

actually i get this like the below method.This will print the selected values in list.

```
name=request.form.getlist('carCarcass')
for x in name:
   print("x",x)
```